# VBA Excel 2010 - Grab Chart Legend

Tags: vba, excel, charts

Currently I am trying to get a charts legend entries, I can get the text values from the individual cells if they are in my workbook but if a chart gets imported into my workbook then my code can't pick up the legends because it's trying to get a cell value that it can't find.

I need the chart legends because people at my work can't seem to grasp the concept of the legends being descending and my userform reflecting that (the userform is for easier manipulation for multiple charts) so I would like the buttons to say which chart line, in this case, it will be dealing with.

`ActiveChart.Legend.LegendEntries(2).Select` will select the legend entry however
`ChartLine2 = ActiveChart.Legend.LegendEntries(2).Value` (or instead of `.Value` I have also tried `.Name` , `.Text` and `.Parent.Name`(though this one only gets the word 'Legend' and not 100% sure why)

My question is what code do I need to grab the name/text of a charts legend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the legend is derived from the Series Name you can use:

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Name
```